# how to restore multiple sql file to different database name for each file in mysql?

Tags: mysql, database

I have hundreds of SQL file which I want to restore all of the databases in different database name for each file.

I look around for a solution, but what I got is something like concat all the files into one SQL file using cat.* and then restore using the concatenated file.

But, what I want is to restore it to a different database so, I think concat is not suitable for my case.

Comment: Please show examples of the files you are dealing with and the OS you are on

Comment: the name of my file like timestamp.dbA.sql.gz . then, I want to restore it to dbA. what I am currently doing is run a script to create db then run script gunzip > filename | mysql -u -p dbname. I'm working on linux

Answer (score 0):

Here's one solution: alternate `USE` commands with your sql files, so you change the default database before the respective database's content. Gather the whole collection together and then pipe that to the input of the mysql client.

Example using bash syntax:

```
( 
  echo "USE database1;" 
  cat file1.sql 
  echo "USE database2;" 
  cat file2.sql
  ...
) | mysql
```

Another solution is to run the mysql client once for each file, and specify the database name as the argument:

```
mysql database1 < file1.sql
mysql database2 < file2.sql
...
```

---

Re your comment:

You can write a loop in bash too.

```
for file in *.sql
do
  db=...
  mysql $db < $file
done
```

The tricky part above is the "`...`" — deciding which db goes with each input SQL file. You haven't described any way to match them, so I don't know what you'd have to do to figure that out. But if you can make that inference somehow from the filename, then you can do this without having to type every file.

Comment: thank you for the answer. but, it seems like I still have to make hundreds of commands right?

Comment: the name of my file like timestamp.dbA.sql.gz . then, I want to restore it to dbA. what I am currently doing is run a script to create db then run script gunzip > filename | mysql -u -p dbname. sorry, I'm new to the bash script. so, it takes time to understand